# Selenium-Java: Code crashes if no element is found

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, findelement, selenium-java

I cannot seem to find a solution on this.  This line of code seems to crash if it cannot find it.  Sometimes it is there and sometimes it is not:

```
Integer dynamicElement =  myDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='CAPTCHA']")).size();
```

I then go on to check the value of my integer, but it crashes when it is not there.  How do you get this not to crash?

Comment: "seems to crash" - Can you be specific or can you share the error what you see on the console? Also share more code which you have tried so that you get help by the community.

Answer (score 0):

### ***findElements***

[`findElements()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By)) finds all the elements within the current page using the given [*`By`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) mechanism. This method will return as soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will return an empty list if the timeout is reached.

---

### An example

For a demonstration, searching for the same element on [Google Search Home Page](https://www.google.com/) perfectly prints ***0*** as no [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) is found.

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  Integer dynamicElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='CAPTCHA']")).size();
  System.out.println(dynamicElement);
  driver.quit();
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  0
  ```

Comment: So you are telling me everything is fine?

Comment: Your right it is returning 1